# Rails- Gem chartkick - Remove axis values from bar_graph

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, chartkick

I have added a bar_chart using gem chartkick in my rails application and don't want to show axis labels and values. Want to show colored lines only. My initial code was following:

```
<%= bar_chart @data, stacked: true, width: "800px", height: "100px" %>
```

which showed following result:
[image]

for removing these numbers I changed my code to:

```
<%= bar_chart @data, stacked: true, width: "800px", height: "100px", discrete: true, library: {vAxis: {gridlines: {color: "transparent"}}} %>
```

But this is not working and the result is same. Any idea how I accomplish this task?